# Recurrent convolution evaluation in R

Tags: r, convolution

I want to compute the convolution of order 3 which is defined as follows:

[image]

So first I compute the convolution of order 2 (this I can do properly). My problem is: how can I keep the convolution of order 2 (which actually is an integral) as a function, in order to use it for the computation of a convolution of order 3? Actually I want to do this recurrently in order to compute the convolution of order $n$.